# In approval workflow in SPD 2013, after approving the task, the item is check out to the user who created it instead of approver group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, approval, online

I have created an approval workflow in SPD 2013 and we have 5 SharePoint groups that have to approve the task one after another. My problem is, when the user creates a document in the library and check-in the document to start the workflow then the workflow sends a task to one of the groups, where they approve it and the approve group has to check-in the document, so that, the workflow moves to next group. Instead, after approving the task by approver, the item is check-out to the initiator (who created the document). So, how to make the item to check-in with approver group, after the task is approved?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the check-out / check-in process included in the workflow, i.e. is the workflow doing the check-out?  If the workflow is doing the check-out then this is expected behavior as the workflow is running as the initiator.  As far as I know a group can't check-out or check-in an item.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have enabled versioning settings and in some stages the workflow is doing the check-in and check-out. After task is assigned to the group, they can check-out the document to edit and check-in the document, however, after the group approves the task, it is checked-out to the initiator, so, can we over ride this with any work flow action?

Comment: Is there anyway, after approver approves the task, the document should be check-out to all the groups or a particular group with spd actions?

Comment: A document can only be checked-out to a user, it can not be checked-out to a group.  The only reason to check-out something is so that only you can edit the file, and other users can not.  I'm not sure why you are checking in and out the document in an approval process.

Comment: Actually, when the task is created for the Approver group, they have to add some information to the document, that's the reason, we are using check-in and check-out for the approvers. However, to move the workflow to the next approver group, the 1st approver group has to check in the document after approving the task.